# How to format Java code in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using ACE Editor to show my Java code. I want to format the java code in Editor. I tried the code like this:

```
var editor = $('.file-content').ace(),
JavaMode = ace.require('ace/mode/java').Mode,
beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify");

editor.getSession().setValue(content);
editor.getSession().setMode(new JavaMode());
beautify.beautify(editor.getSession());
```

But I got the beautiful code like this:

```
publicclassHelloWorld{publicstaticvoidmain(String args[]){System 
.out.println(1);
}}
```

How can I format Java code in Ace Editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of hooking JS Beautifier into your existing Ace Editor.

```js
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
var txtAra = document.querySelector('textarea[name="editor"]');
var jsbOpts = {
  indent_size : 2
};

editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/java");
syncEditor();

// Main Logic
setTimeout(formatCode, 1000); // Format sample Java after 1 second.

// Functions
function syncEditor() {
  editor.getSession().setValue(txtAra.value);
}
function commitChanges() {
  txtAra.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
}
function formatCode() {
  var session = editor.getSession();
  session.setValue(js_beautify(session.getValue(), jsbOpts));
}
```

```css
.title {
  font-size: 1.67em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#editor {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}
textarea[name="editor"] {
  display: none;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="title">Ace Editor - Java Format</div>
  <textarea name="editor">public class SpringTest {public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {System.out.print("Hello world");}}</textarea>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xj2qn095/)

Comment: Please remember that if you add code with < and > etc in your logic, like ArrayList<String>, then JS Beautifier will convert to ArrayList < String > -- and this would cause compilation issues. So be sure about the content and the risk involved when you are trying to format.

Answer (score 0):

Ace doesn't provide a way to beautify java, you'll need to use another program for that.